# What is actually returned?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am recently learning express.js. The code below is copied from the router lib of express.js.

```
var proto = module.exports = function(options) {
  options = options || {};

  function router(req, res, next) {
    router.handle(req, res, next);
  }

  // mixin Router class functions
  router.__proto__ = proto;

  router.params = {};
  router._params = [];
  router.caseSensitive = options.caseSensitive;
  router.strict = options.strict;
  router.stack = [];

  return router;
  };
```

My question is what is returned if I call

```
var Router = require('./router');
var _router = new Router(...);
```

What is `_router`? Is it the function `router(req, res, next)`? If yes, can I call `_router(req, res, next);`?

If I am wrong, could someone please explain what does the code do?

If yes, why don't they just do it like:

```
var proto = module.exports = function(options) {
options = options || {};

var router = {};

// mixin Router class functions
router.__proto__ = proto;

router.params = {};
router._params = [];
router.caseSensitive = options.caseSensitive;
router.strict = options.strict;
router.stack = [];

return router;
};
```

Comment: Yes and yes. Though modifying the prototype of functions is a little odd...

Comment: I don't understand why do they return a router function here. Why just do it like

Comment: For the *why*, ask the developers of express.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

```
var Router = require('./router');
var _router = new Router(...);
```

`var Router` is a object of created by the `function router(req, res, next)`, and your `var router` is a new object of `Router`. In javascript almost everything is an object. You can read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

If they use your aproach they won't have a constructor. And they use the constructor to do `router.handle(req, res, next);` I don't know why they need the handle, you can study more the code or ask the developers. But you probably can use the `var router new Router(req,res,next);` if you know what the params do.

Comment: I don't think you can call `var _router = new Router(req, res, next);`.  The `Router` returned by the `require` is `function(option){...}`. you can only call `_router(req, res, next);`.

Comment: You right, I misunderstood the a lot of "router" in same function and forgot about the first funciont. For the name of variables I belive the router(req, res, next) is used with promise to resolve something later, so you can pass the route in chain. http://know.cujojs.com/tutorials/async/mastering-async-error-handling-with-promises.html.md